PayPal Payouts Integration with Firebase Functions in iOS App
I'm working on an iOS app that requires paying out winnings to players using PayPal. I'm integrating PayPal payouts through Firebase Cloud Functions, but I keep encountering errors.
Here's the client side code:
I'm using GTMSessionFetcher to call the Firebase Cloud Function for PayPal payouts.
import UIKit
import GTMSessionFetcherCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFunctions

class WinningsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var balanceLabel: UILabel!
    var withdrawPaypalButton: UIButton!
    var withdrawVenmoButton: UIButton!
    var balanceListener: ListenerRegistration?
    lazy var functions = Functions.functions()
    var currentFetcher: GTMSessionFetcher?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        setupBalanceListener()
    }
    
    deinit {
        balanceListener?.remove()
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        // UI setup code...
    }
    
    func setupBalanceListener() {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
        let userUID = user.uid
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        balanceListener = db.collection("playerBalances").document(userUID).addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists, let balance = document.data()?["balance"] as? Double {
                self?.balanceLabel.text = String(format: "Balance: $%.2f", balance)
                self?.updateButtonState(balance: balance)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateButtonState(balance: Double) {
        let isEnabled = balance > 0.0
        withdrawPaypalButton.isEnabled = isEnabled
        withdrawVenmoButton.isEnabled = isEnabled
    }
    
    @objc func withdrawPaypalButtonTapped() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Withdraw with PayPal", message: "Please enter your PayPal email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "PayPal email"
        }
        let withdrawAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Withdraw", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let email = alertController.textFields?.first?.text, !email.isEmpty else { return }
            self?.initiatePaypalPayout(recipientEmail: email)
        }
        alertController.addAction(withdrawAction)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func initiatePaypalPayout(recipientEmail: String) {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
        currentFetcher?.stopFetching()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userUID = user.uid
        db.collection("playerBalances").document(userUID).getDocument { [weak self] (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists, let balance = document.data()?["balance"] as? Double {
                guard let url = URL(string: "https://us-central1-your-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/withdrawPayPal") else { return }
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                let payload: [String: Any] = ["data": ["recipientEmail": recipientEmail, "amount": balance]]
                do {
                    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payload, options: [])
                } catch {
                    return
                }
                self?.currentFetcher = GTMSessionFetcher(request: request)
                self?.currentFetcher?.beginFetch { data, error in
                    self?.currentFetcher = nil
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        self?.showPaymentErrorAlert(error: error.localizedDescription)
                    } else if let data = data,
                              let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
                              let success = result["success"] as? Bool, success {
                        self?.showPaymentSuccessAlert()
                    } else {
                        self?.showPaymentErrorAlert(error: "Unexpected error occurred.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showPaymentSuccessAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Payment Successful", message: "Your payout has been successfully initiated!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func showPaymentErrorAlert(error: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Payment Error", message: "There was an error initiating your payout: \(error)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

Server Side:
index.js:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const { withdrawPayPal } = require('./paypalPayout');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.withdrawPayPal = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
        },
        body: null
    };

    try {
        const result = await withdrawPayPal(data, context);
        response.body = JSON.stringify(result);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        response.statusCode = 500;
        response.body = JSON.stringify({ error: error.message });
        return response;
    }
});

paypalPayout.js:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const paypal = require('@paypal/payouts-sdk');

const clientId = 'YOUR_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID';
const clientSecret = 'YOUR_PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET';
const environment = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
const client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);

const getPayPalAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await client.fetchAccessToken();
        return response.result.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting PayPal access token:', error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Failed to get PayPal access token.');
    }
};

const createPayout = async (recipientEmail, amount) => {
    const requestBody = {
        "sender_batch_header": {
            "sender_batch_id": `Payouts_${new Date().getTime()}`,
            "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
            "email_message": "You have received a payout! Thanks for using our service!"
        },
        "items": [{
            "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
            "amount": {
                "value": amount.toFixed(2),
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "receiver": recipientEmail,
            "note": "Thank you for your patronage!",
            "sender_item_id": `Item_${new Date().getTime()}`
        }]
    };

    let request = new paypal.payouts.PayoutsPostRequest();
    request.requestBody(requestBody);

    try {
        const response = await client.execute(request);
        return response.result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("PayPal Payout Error:", error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Error creating payout', error);
    }
};

exports.withdrawPayPal = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }

    const { recipientEmail, amount } = data.data;  // Adjusted to retrieve from data object
    if (!recipientEmail || !amount) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with two arguments: recipientEmail and amount.');
    }

    const userId = context.auth.uid;
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const userBalanceRef = db.collection('playerBalances').doc(userId);
    const userBalanceDoc = await userBalanceRef.get();

    if (!userBalanceDoc.exists) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'User balance not found');
    }

    const userBalance = parseFloat(userBalanceDoc.data().balance);
    const payoutAmount = parseFloat(amount);

    if (userBalance < payoutAmount) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'Insufficient balance');
    }

    try {
        const payoutResponse = await createPayout(recipientEmail, payoutAmount);

        const batchStatus = payoutResponse.batch_header.batch_status;
        const batchId = payoutResponse.batch_header.payout_batch_id;

        if (batchStatus === 'PENDING' || batchStatus === 'SUCCESS') {
            await userBalanceRef.update({
                balance: userBalance - payoutAmount
            });
            return { success: true, message: 'Payout processed successfully!', batchId, batchStatus };
        } else {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Payout failed with status: ' + batchStatus);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Payout failed.', error.message);
    }
});

Despite following this approach, I'm encountering the error: Unexpected error occurred. when initiating the payout. The Cloud Function logs indicate issues but do not provide a clear resolution.
Questions:

Is there anything wrong with my request payload or the way I call the Cloud Function?
Are there any known issues or better practices when using GTMSessionFetcher for this kind of request?
What could be the possible causes for this Unexpected error occurred message?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Why are you trying to invoke the function using a direct URL request when you are supposed to use the provided iOS client SDK as described in the documentation?  If you don't use the provided SDK, you need to follow the callable HTTP protocol, which is not terribly simple.

If you don't intend to use callables as documented (you don't seem to be using any of its conveniences), maybe you just want to use a normal HTTP function instead.

Hi Doug,
Thank you for your feedback. My main goal is to enable PayPal payouts in my iOS app. I originally attempted to use the iOS client SDK, but I'm encountering issues with initiating payouts.
Would using Braintree be a viable route for PayPal payouts? If so, could you provide detailed guidance or documentation references for implementing PayPal payouts using Braintree?
Thank you for your help.
